# how to stop setInterval function in react

Tags: reactjs

building a speed-type-game in **react**
in my app there countdown feature using `setinterval function`
me want to stop countdown when it reaches 0

my code here

```
const countdownValue = 15  
const [sec , setSec ] = useState(countdownValue)
let timer


function start(){
 timer = setInterval( () => {
     setSec( sec => sec - 1)
 },1000)   
}

if(sec <= 0){
  clearInterval(timer)
}
```

me tried `clearinterval function` to stop countdown but its not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the component re-renders after the state change. So your timer becomes undefined. What you can do is: move it outside your component or use useRef from React

```
const countdownValue = 15  
const [sec , setSec ] = useState(countdownValue)
const timer = useRef()

function start(){
 timer.current = setInterval( () => {
     setSec( sec => sec - 1)
 },1000)   
}

useEffect(() => {
   if (sec <= 0) {
      clearinterval(timer.current)
   }
}, [sec])
```